# Changing space in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

As my figure captions are very long, I am trying to set single spacing within lines of each entry and double spacing between each entry in list of figures. However i still want to keep my whole document double spacing. How do I do that?

Comment: you asked a similar question earlier today but you are ignoring requests that you show an example document.  possibly you can use `\singlespacing` before the toc and `\doublespacing` after it but unless you show an example document it is impossible to guess.

Comment: do you need long captions in the list, normally people use `\caption[short version]{long caption text here}` to have a long caption under the figure but a shorter text in the list.

Comment: Indeed @DavidCarlisle, I wrote him/her the same advice. But it does not seem to be the case. We are blind. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527962/one-figure-caption-to-big-in-the-first-page-of-list-of-figures/527989#527989]